# Stop djoser from adding API url to the frontend url set in PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL

Tags: django-rest-framework, djoser

I have a DRF API using djoser to handle password reset. The password reset workflow is working well except for the `PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL`

When I set my frontend page URL in that setting for Djoser it keeps concatenating the API URL  to the frontend page URL. How can I stop that

for more context here are my Djoser settings showing the URL I set for  `PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL`

```
DJOSER = {
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'http://localhost:3000/auth/confirm-password-reset/{uid}/{token}',
    'ACTIVATION_URL': '#/activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_SHOW_EMAIL_NOT_FOUND': True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_RETYPE': True,
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'password_reset': 'djoser.serializers.SendEmailResetSerializer',
        'password_reset_confirm': 'djoser.serializers.PasswordResetConfirmSerializer',
        'password_reset_confirm_retype': 'djoser.serializers.PasswordResetConfirmRetypeSerializer',
        'set_password': 'djoser.serializers.SetPasswordSerializer',
        'set_password_retype': 'djoser.serializers.SetPasswordRetypeSerializer',
        'current_user': 'djoser.serializers.UserSerializer',
    },
    'PERMISSIONS': {

    }
}
```

and here is the URL I receive in my email

[image: email screenshot]

as you can see **http://127.0.0.1:8000** the API URL has been added to the frontend URL I set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appear to be two ways to set a new DOMAIN name explicitly:

1. Add a `DOMAIN` and `SITE_NAME` [to the Django settings](https://django-templated-mail.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html)
2. Use the [Django Sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/sites/) and set the domain name there

Sites isn't often useful, so use #1 unless something else fails. The only other option is overriding all email templates so you can specify the full url.

---

1. Djoser only supports paths/fragments, **not** full urls
2. Links are created using `{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}/{{ url|safe }}`
3. A package called [`templated_mail`](https://django-templated-mail.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) is used to send these emails
4. That package sets the `protocol`, `domain` and `site_name`

The [code for setting the variables](https://github.com/sunscrapers/django-templated-mail/blob/master/templated_mail/mail.py) for use in the email template is:

```
site = get_current_site(self.request)
domain = context.get('domain') or (
    getattr(settings, 'DOMAIN', '') or site.domain
)
protocol = context.get('protocol') or (
    'https' if self.request.is_secure() else 'http'
)
site_name = context.get('site_name') or (
    getattr(settings, 'SITE_NAME', '') or site.name
)
```

The `http` vs `https` decision is made for you, but since those are almost always the same its probably not an issue in practice.

Comment: So does option number one where I set `DOMAIN` and `SITE_NAME` require me to install the package `django-templated-email`

Comment: No, its installed by Djoser.

Comment: Life saver. This helps with my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76737590/djoser-reset-password-flow-to-javascript-frontend-vue)